# Is there any tidy way to do reverse compare operation?

Tags: c#

I have a requirement that

```
if (flag)  
{
   if (valA >= valB)  
   // some logics
}
else
{
   if (valA <= valB)
   // some logics
}
```

Is there anyway to do the above except using the "duplicate code" kinda way ?

I thought of doing that in a way of

```
var reverseFactor = flag ? 1 : -1;
if (reverseFactor * valA >= reverseFactor * valB)
```

Or using

```
Func<int, int, bool> ?
```

Comment: Are the `// some logics` the same logic?

Comment: Let say the remarked blocks are "mostly" identical. Well, they will be identical after refactoring. =).

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the two conditions are not mutually exclusive, so you could not use the "XOR with a flag" trick to invert conditions:

```
if (flag ^ (a < b))
```

You can opt for a less readable

```
if ((a == b) || (flag ^ (a < b)))
```

Comment: This is something I'm looking for. But, as you mentioned, it's not quite readable. Maybe wrapping that into an extensions method?

Comment: @cscmh99 Wrapping into an extension method would work, as long as you give your method a nice readable name. Take two IComparable objects and a flag, and return a result based on the expression.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (flag ? valA >= valB : valA <= valB)
  // stuff
```

Since boolean expressions can themselves be part of other expressions.

Comment: This doesn't account for if he needs to do different logic for false / true

Comment: @MikeDub which as per the comment on the question, we don't want it to do.

Answer (score 0):

You can shorten the syntax to avoid double if statements as you are not doing anything unless 'both ifs' are met:

```
if (flag && valA >= valB)
{
  //true flag logic
}
else if (!flag && valA <= valB)
{
  //false flag logic
}
```

So if you want the logic to produce a value, then you can turn it into a ternary statement:

```
var result = (flag && valA >= valB) ? //True logic : if(!flag && valA <= valB) //False logic;
```

But this would require a 2nd if statement.

Answer (score 0):

What about this:

```
if (Math.Sign(valA-valB) != (flag ? -1 : 1))
{
    //some logic
}
```